# How to get content of a page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a page called About us and have the permalink as : http://virtual1.com/index.php/about-us

I also queried to get the page content but what I got was blank (it didn't show the date last modified the page nor the author, the content paragraph)
Here is the code :

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'page',
    'slug' => 'about-us'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php get_header(  ); ?>
<?php
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();?>
<!--Main body-->
<div id="content">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="content-inner">
                            <!-- Left sidebar -->
             <div id="component" class="col-sm-12">
             <main role="main">

              <div id="system-message-container">
              </div>

<article class="page-item page-item__blog page-item__" itemscope="">
    <div class="item_info">
    <dl class="item_info_dl">
        <dt class="article-info-term">
        </dt>
            //Get the date last modified of the page
            <dd>
                <time datetime="2018-02-26 10:14" class="item_published">
                    <?php get_the_modified_date(  ); ?>     
                </time>
            </dd>
            <dd>
            //Get the author of the page
            <address class="item_createdby">
            <?php get_the_author(  ); ?>            
            </address>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

//Get the paragraph in the page here
<div class="item_fulltext">
    <p>
        <?php echo $content?>
    </p>    
</div>
<!--End loop-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!--End of main body-->
<?php get_footer(  ); ?>
```

Comment: Does it show any html-tags (even without content)?
Or is the html-source completely empty?

Comment: It shows html tag, but the content loaded inside the tags are empty

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in **page.php**, in place of **$content**  function **the_content()** will do your work.

```
<?php 
      get_header(); 
      $page_id=get_the_ID();
      $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $page_id ) );

      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
?>
       <div id="content">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="content-inner">
                            <!-- Left sidebar -->
             <div id="component" class="col-sm-12">
             <main role="main">

              <div id="system-message-container">
              </div>

<article class="page-item page-item__blog page-item__" itemscope="">
    <div class="item_info">
    <dl class="item_info_dl">
        <dt class="article-info-term">
        </dt>
            //Get the date last modified of the page
            <dd>
                <time datetime="2018-02-26 10:14" class="item_published">
                    <?php get_the_modified_date(); ?>     
                </time>
            </dd>
            <dd>
            //Get the author of the page
            <address class="item_createdby">
            <?php get_the_author(); ?>            
            </address>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

//Get the paragraph in the page here
<div class="item_fulltext">
    <p>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </p>    
</div>
<?php 
      endwhile;
?>
```